# VS Code fails while creating a Docker dev environment in Linux

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-code

I'd like to use the Docker development environments extension in Visual Studio Code. I'm using Ubuntu Linux 22.10 and Visual Studio Code 1.78.2, installed using `snap` package manager.

When I want to create a new Docker dev container, the following output is shown in the console.

```
[19 ms] Dev Containers 0.292.0 in VS Code 1.78.2 (b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435).
[19 ms] Start: Resolving remote host
[26 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[26 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[104 ms] Server API version: 1.41
[105 ms] Start: Run: docker build -f /tmp/vsch-username/bootstrap-image/0.292.0/bootstrap.Dockerfile -t vsc-volume-bootstrap /tmp/vsch-username/bootstrap-image/0.292.0
unable to prepare context: path "/tmp/vsch-username/bootstrap-image/0.292.0" not found
[187 ms] Command failed: docker build -f /tmp/vsch-username/bootstrap-image/0.292.0/bootstrap.Dockerfile -t vsc-volume-bootstrap /tmp/vsch-username/bootstrap-image/0.292.0
[187 ms] Exit code 1
```

Copying the command to the shell, it gives the same result. However, when you copy that Dockerfile and run it in a subdirectory of user home directory, it is successful, like so.

```
$ cd ~/dev
$ cp /tmp/vsch-username/bootstrap-image/0.292.0/bootstrap.Dockerfile .
$ mv bootstrap.Dockerfile Dockerfile
$ docker build .
```

In my opinion, this is rather an access control issue, somehow Docker daemon is not able to read the `/tmp` folder. I tried giving 7777 permissions to `/tmp` folder, recursively, no luck there.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It definitely looks like a permission issue. Try uninstalling VS Code via snap and download it back again from its official website: https://code.visualstudio.com/Download. I've experienced some permission issues with package managers in the past, so it might be worth a try.

Comment: @BerkayKaplan while searching for this specific error, I stumbled upon permission issues due to Snap's installation script of Docker, I'll try with the official installation method to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `snap` package manager is not able to set the permissions properly, at least as the same with what `apt`-based installation does. Uninstalled Docker using `sudo snap remove --purge docker`, followed the official installation steps from [Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/). Works like a charm now.